# Problems with python interpertor after ssh with paramiko into a remote machine

Tags: python, ssh, ipython, paramiko

I have a problem with paramiko. For some reason when I use python and paramiko to SSH into a 
remote machine which has anaconda installed on I never see the anaconda version of python.
for example

```
ssh.connect('remote_machine',username='User') 
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("which python") 
print stdout.readlines()
```

which gives me

```
/usr/bin/python
```

but when I use regular ssh from terminal to the remote machine I get what I expect

```
/Users/farside/anaconda/bin
```

Am I missing something in the way paramiko works ? Maybe there is some problem with the way the bashrc paths are read when using paramiko ssh ?
Thank you!

Comment: Run `ssh.exec_command()` with parameter `get_pty=False` and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @ByteNudger - that didn't work, but what did work is to just do source bash_profile after I ssh with paramiko. I still don't understand why that is though(the fact that I have to load the profile manually).

Comment: It looks like the paramiko session isn't a login shell. Have a look at these question for a better understanding: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40708/15435, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43953/15435 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/15435

Comment: A way to get things running is to create a `~/.profile` which source the `bash_profile`. But it's not a solution within paramiko and you maybe have to do it on every server you want to connect.

Comment: Thanks @ByteNudger! I understand it a bit better now